# Why is the net charge between two adjacent plates of capacitors in series considered neutral?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, batteries

The right-most plate of C1 connected to the left-most plate of C2  is said to be isolated from the circuit.
How is the left-most plate considered positive and the right-most plate negative?[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to know why the adjacent plates of the capacitors is said to be isolated from rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential difference across the battery creates a positive charge on the left hand plate of $C_1$ and a negative charge on the right hand plate of $C_2$. The charges in turn creates a potential difference between the two capacitors, which causes equal and opposite charges to accumulate on the opposite plate of each capacitor. Note that potential differences can be mediated by the electric field - there is no need for a physical connection between the two plates of each capacitor. Indeed, if there were such a connection then the components would be resistors, not capacitors.

Comment: Thanks mate ☺️.

I really like how plain the explanation was.